# Prove traffic when I own the server

Tags: php, ssl

I work for the goverment and one project targets employees that might apply something from their employer, for example a vacation period. They login with username and password.

I want to record their actions and be able to proof that they did so, for example, when one asks for 3 days off, I must record it in a way so I can prove the time and what they asked. So later they can't deny it.

Currently, the best I can do is to log all the data (PHP 7.3 $_SERVER, $_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION), get a trusted timestamp from our official TS provider and save this. Server, Centos 7.

How do I proof however that this data is not manufactured? The connection is encrypted, so I can't get the employee's ISP do return any logs.  We also own the server so there is no 3rd party server provider to ensure the traffic.

Is there a way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why you don’t use ntlm, so the login would be there ADDS login already, can’t cheat it

Comment: This ultimately isn't a technical question.  You need to determine what whoever administers the program would accept as suitable evidence.

Comment: `How do I proof however that this data is not manufactured` - First you need to clearly define who you are protecting against. If nobody else has root/admin access on the server, then nobody else should be able to tamper with the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest implementing two-factor authentication which sends an SMS/TXT to the user to verify they are the one logging in.

[Google Authenticator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator) might be another solution.

You have not provided a lot about your environment.  It's apparent you have a PHP server installed somewhere, but I have no idea if it's Windows or Linux (or something else).

With more info, it might be possible to give yo more specific advice.